Change direction of > 5 pins with PIO asm
My understanding is that this changes the direction of up to 5 OUT pins:
out pindirs 31

In the above example, 31 would be all 5 bits set to 1, so the first 5 OUT pins would be set to outputs.
How do we change the direction of more than 5 pins?
For example, I have 8 pins starting from GPIO18, skipping the unused pins 23-25 and then I use pins GPIO26,27,28.
How can I change the direction of pins 26-28 if the last parameter is only 5 bits?

The only other option I see is with an OUT PINDIRS,<bit_count>. This requires that OSR is loaded with your pattern, which more-or-less moves the problem of setting any constant larger than 5 bits.
Doing this dynamically on-the-fly requires cooperation from the CPU because you need to push your pattern to the shift register in order for OUT to access it. If you have two separate configurations you want to toggle between quickly you can store the patterns in X and Y and use something like MOV OSR,X/OUT PINDIRS,16.
If this is only required occasionally you can have the CPU pause the PIO and change the directions from the CPU, then resume the PIO.
Not being able to hard-code 16/32-bit patterns is an annoying "limitation" but usually you don't need to do that.
In your case, maybe you just want to flip all pins from input to output. You can do that with MOV OSR,!NULL for example, which sets all bits to one. Combine this with the possibility for a PIO to have different mappings for OUT, SET, IN, and side-set, so you may be able to come up with a workaround.

Ah! Yes that may work. I'll give it a go later. I sent the data using a 16bit value for the non-contiguous 8-bit value so I'll see if I can do something similar with PINDIRS as you suggest. It's just the 8 pins I need to sent to input. I'm emulating an 8-bit ROM chip so it needs to stop asserting the data bus when my output enable becomes high. Love the Amiga avatar by the way!

Actually.. I suspect I am getting mixed up with SET and OUT. If OUT takes the OSR and configures the PINDIRS with that, then it all makes sense now. I'll accept your answer. Fingers crossed it works later when I wire something up to test it :-)
